# Zend-form in controller and processing this form in specific action - how can I do this?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Im my layout I have search form, so it's displayed on every page.
It looks like this:

```
<?
$form = new SearchIndexForm();
$form->setAction($this->configuration['BaseUrl']Index/search); 
echo $form; ?>
```

I would like to have sth like that: when someone click submit button, the form redirects to the action "search" on "Index" controller, where there is processing the form values.

So, what should I do, to have equivallent to this, which will be working with data send by post method from form in layout?

```
if($this->_request->isPost()){
$formValues = $this->_request->getParams();
    if ($form->isValid($formValues)){
    ...
    }
}
```

With the above, when I click submit, it gets me to the /Index/search, but nothing happens...

The form itself worked perfectly when it was in one action.

Comment: Are you instantiating the form in the search action?

Comment: yes, I have something like this in search action: $form = new SearchIndexForm(); but with or without it, search doesn't work.

Comment: Extra info will be needed then. Does the request reach the action OK? Does the form validate? At which point does it fail?

Comment: if($this->_request->isPost()){ it seems it never goes inside this "if", so I suppose it's a wrong construction for this. How can I get data from that form search in layout?

Comment: What does `print_r($this->_getAllParams())` spit out? Is your search query there? If it is not, then the form fails to send any data. If it is, them it's probably in GET, not POST.

Comment: No, my search query isn't there. But it can't be in GET, I have method POST asigned to my form :)

Comment: Odd. As if there was an additional redirect along the way...?

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue? I know my answer got a vote up but I don't know if it actually helped you.

Comment: I haven't done any redirections, not intentionally that's for sure :)

Comment: I think that you need to check the form setup again because if your post isn't submitting then it might be a problem with that. I've tried to emulate your setup on my machine and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're doing everything right but I think that there is some code that you should change.

Try the following code

```
 $request = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest();

//or you can try
//$request = $this->getRequest();

if($request->isPost()){

$form = new SearchIndexForm();

    if ($form->isValid( $request->getPost() ) ){

        echo 'This should output if the form is valid' . PHP_EOL;

    }
}
```

I don't like accessing variables directly as you did in $this->_request because Zend might have to do doing things to the variables to make them 'proper'. I know that sometimes nothing is done but better safe than sorry. Unless you're positive about it, which I'm usually not positive about unless I've really looked at the code.

Comment: thanks for answer, but it still doesn't work...:) print_r($request) give me this result: Zend_Controller_Request_Http Object ( [_paramSources:protected] => Array ( [0] => _GET [1] => _POST ) [_requestUri:protected] => /gallery/public/index/search [_baseUrl:protected] => /gallery/public [_basePath:protected] => [_pathInfo:protected] => /index/search [_params:protected] => Array ( [controller] => index [action] => search [module] => default ) [_aliases:protected] =>

Comment: Array ( ) [_dispatched:protected] => 1 [_module:protected] => default [_moduleKey:protected] => module [_controller:protected] => index [_controllerKey:protected] => controller [_action:protected] => search [_actionKey:protected] => action )

Comment: What is in the $_POST variable when you're in the new controller?

Comment: In your print out, near the beginning, the request has the _GET and _POST variables set. try printing these out. If they don't contain anything then your form isn't submitting any data.

Comment: well, I found what was the problem... I had default redirecting to action search, so I didn't find out, that I had in my form wrongly defined "action = " :) Thanks for help, I'm just totally stupid sometimes :)

Comment: thanks for the credit even though i didn't really help then. take care. happy coding.